# how to display a message to Management Studio output area when no records retrived

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

i am looking for a soloution that provides following operations on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio R2:

- retrieve some records from database,table EX
- if no record returned by query then display a message in MS SQL Server
  **Management Studio output section area**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following code

```
declare @n int
set @n = (select ISNULL(count(*),0) from table_name)
if(@n=0)
print 'not result'
else
select * from table_name
```

or

```
if(select count(*) from table_name)=0
print 'not result'
else
select * from table_name
```